# RNG seed selection highly affects simulation otucomes

Tags: random, simulation, omnet++, random-seed

I'm developing for the first time a simulation in Omnet++ 5.4 that makes use of the queueinglib library available. In particular, I've built a simple model that comprehends a server and some passive queues.

I've repeated the simulation different times, setting different seeds and parameters, as written in the Omnet Simulation Manual, here is my omnetpp.ini:

```
# specify how many times a run needs to be repeated
repeat = 100
# default: different seed for each run
# seed-set = ${runnumber}
seed-set = ${repetition} # I tried both lines

OppNet.source.interArrivalTime = exponential(${10,5,2.5}s)
```

This produces 300 runs, 100 repetitions for each value of the interArrivalTime distribution parameter.

However, I'm observing some "strange" behaviour, namely, the resulting statistics are highly variable according to the RNG seed.
For example, considering the lengths of the queues in my model, I have in the majority of the runs values smaller than 10, while in a few others a mean value that differs in orders of magnitude (85000, 45000?).

Does this mean that my implementation is wrong? Or is it possible that the random seed selection could influence the simulation outcomes so heavily?

Any help or hint is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot rule out that your implementation is wrong without seeing it, but it is entirely possible that you just happened to configure a chaotic scenario.
And in that case, yes, any minor change in the inputs (in this case the PRNG seed) might cause a major divergence in the results.

**EDIT**:

Especially considering a given (non-trivial) queuing network, if you are varying the "load" (number/rate of incoming jobs/messages, with some random distribution), you might observe different "regimes" in the results:

- with very light load, there is barely any queuing
- with a really heavy load (close, or at max capacity), most queues are almost always loaded, or even growing constantly without limit
- and somewhere in between the two, you might get this erratic behavior, where sometimes a couple of queues suddenly grow really deep, then are emptied, then different queues are loaded up, and so on; as a function of either time, or the PRNG seed, or both - this is what I mean by chaotic

But this is just speculation...

Answer (score 0):

Nobody can say whether your implementation is right or wrong without seeing it.  However, there are some general rules that apply to queues which you should be aware of.  You say that you're varying the interArrivalTime distribution parameter.  A very important concept in queueing is the *traffic intensity*, which is the ratio of the interarrival rate to the service rate.  If that ratio is less than one, the line length can vary by a great deal but in the long run there will be time intervals when the queue empties out because on average the server can handle more customers than arrive.  This is a stable queue.  However, if that ratio is greater than one, the queue will grow unboundedly.  The longer you run the system, the longer the line will get. The thing that surprises many people is that the line will also go to infinity asymptotically when traffic intensity is equal to one.

The other thing to know is that the closer the traffic intensity gets to one for a stable queue, the greater the variability is.  That's because the average increases, but there will always be periods of line length zero as described above. In order to have zeros always present but have the average increasing, there must be times where the queue length gets above the average, which implies the variability must be increasing.  Changing the random number seed gives you some visibility on the magnitude of the variance that's possible at any slice of time.

Bottom line here is that you may just be seeing evidence that queues are weirder and more variable than you thought.